# Substituição de caracteres em uma string

Tags: javascript, string

Eu tenho uma *string* a ser passada pelo formulário e gostaria de substituir alguns caracteres dela para que ela fique na forma de numeral:

```
if(form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value.includes("R$")){
            form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value.replace("R$","");
            alert(form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value);
        }
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Não está funcionando, não sei porque, eu coloquei o alert pra ver como fica a variável depois do replace, mas não está tirando o "R$"

Comment: Vc sabe se ao menos entra no IF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que não está atribuindo o valor para a variável. O [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) não altera a variável, ela manipula o valor e retorna esse novo valor. Se não guardá-lo em algum lugar, ele é perdido. Assim funciona:

```js
if (form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value.includes("R$")){
    form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value = form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value.replace("R$", "");
    alert(form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value);
}
```

```html
<form name = "form1">
    <input name = "autonomoBonusBruto" value = "R$">
</form>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/ChangeHtml.js).

Answer (score 1):

Cara, não há problema algum com esse código. A tua variável contém "R$" e vc a substitui por "". O que vc gostaria que aparecesse no alert()?

```js
if (form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value.includes("R$")){
    form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value = form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value.replace("R$", "");
    alert(form1.autonomoBonusBruto.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input name="autonomoBonusBruto" value="R$10,00">
</form>
```

Comment: Você está achando que a minha resposta é a pergunta? Ou apenas copiou a minha resposta como solução?